# awaitng async eventhandler does not waits the method to continue

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am developing a *WinForms Application*.
I created a custom Control (inheriting from *Control* class). It has its own Eventhandlers to allow the forms to observe some events.

```
public  event EventHandler<TextBoxFilterEventArgs> DataGetFiltered;
```

My issues came when, inside the control,in some specific situations I perform a call to the registered receivers:

```
this.Enabled=false;
if (DataGetFiltered != null)
   DataGetFiltered(this, new TextBoxFilterEventArgs(itemsFiltered));
this.Enabled=true;
```

You can see I set the control disabled/enabled before and after the call.
The form containing the control is registering some methods to that event in a async way:

```
txtFilter.DataGetFiltered += async (s, e) => await txtFilterByDesc_DataGetFiltered(s, e);

private async Task txtFilterByDesc_DataGetFiltered(object sender, TextBoxFilterEventArgs e)
{
     await Task.Run(()=>/*some code*/);
}
```

What happens?
The control calls to the events handlers registered but it continues to run `this.Enabled=true;`without waiting previous call to finish( but it has been awaited!) 
What's going on?

Comment: Attaching async lambda to a synchronous event is equivalent of attaching `async void` handler. So while `awaits` inside work, the handler itself is not awaited in any way by the caller.

Comment: Ok , many thanls @IvanStoev, so how a handler can handle async calls?  is there a workarounf for that?

Comment: Nope. The disable / enable code must be inside the handler, not at the call site.

Comment: The control is a textbox that i want to get enabled/disabled during the handling of eventhandlers.  I have to move that logic to the handler itself?

Comment: You have to define your event similar to this [AsyncEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynceventhandler?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and do `if (DataGetFiltered != null) await DataGetFiltered(...)`

Comment: @IvanStoev No, it's will work only with single handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens?

After disabling control, your event handling code runs asynchronous delegate.
The delegate ultimately calls `Task.Run` and offloads some work to a thread pool thread.
Then delegate returns, and control becomes enabled again, but scheduled task still runs in background.

> The control is a textbox that i want to get enabled/disabled during the handling of eventhandlers. I have to move that logic to the handler itself?

Short answer: yes.

More detailed answer: while you're using standard .NET event handling pattern, you have to move this logic into event handler. Event doesn't know about handlers implementation. They can be either synchronous, or asynchronous. So, all you can do is to let event handler to manage `Enabled` property.

Technically, you can invent some sort of asynchronous event handler, but, actually, you shouldn't. .NET developers know, that event delegate is of type `EventHandler`/`EventHandler<T>`. Custom event delegate type breaks well-known pattern.

Comment: what do you think about using  AsyncEventHandler inside library Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading ?

Comment: @Badulake: the same as about inventing your own asynchronous event delegate. Besides, `AsyncEventHandler` isn't a part of .NET, it's a part of VS SDK -> here comes the question, how to deploy your application with such dependency.

Comment: Ok, so you think I should stay with the well know pattern, and forget about implementations  (also de Microsoft ones)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your *event handler* uses `await`, but your *called method* doesn't wait for the handler! So, you need to create your own event that returns `Task`, like the following:

```
public delegate Task DataGetFiltered(object sender, TextBoxFilterEventArgs e);
public event DataGetFiltered OnDataGetFiltered;
```

And in the called method:

```
if (null != this.OnDataGetFiltered)
{
    var args = new TextBoxFilterEventArgs(itemsFiltered);
    foreach (var handler in this.OnDataGetFiltered.GetInvocationList().Cast<DataGetFiltered>())
    {
        await handler(this, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fit .NET event handler pattern. It's a bad idea.